# PHP 8.2 error_log_mode won't make file writeable

Tags: php

[PHP 8.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log-mode) contains a new INI setting, `error_log_mode`.

This works to set the `r` and `x` bits, but NOT the `w` bit, which will only be set on the user mode.

(I'm trying to make the error log writeable by the group, so that my login user in that group can delete the log file without `sudo`. 0664 should suffice, but that doesn't change the mode at all. I'm testing with 0777 to confirm that the mode changes, but the writeable bits still remain unset.)

Example:

```php
// Yes, 0777 is extreme, but it shows that the error mode successfully
// changes, just without including the writeable bits :-(
echo var_export(ini_set('error_log_mode', '0777'), true) . "\n";
echo var_export(ini_set('error_log_mode', '0777'), true) . "\n";

undefinedFunction();
```

This shows that the error mode is changed successfully from 0644 to 0777:

```
'0644'
'0777'
```

But the file is actually using 0755:

```
$ ls -l php-error.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 210 Mar  7 07:27 php-error.log
```

Comment: Why would you set a text file as executable? Changing the mode to `0777` is bad practice.

Comment: Yes, this was an extreme example to show that even with all bits set, the writeable bits aren't granted. I'm trying with 0664, which doesn't change the mode at all (from 0644), so I added more bits to verify that it was doing *something*.

I've updated my post to explain that better. I think my question is still worthy of StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Does `php-error.log` exists prior `ini_set`? [File permissions of existing files are not changed](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/error_log_mode)

Comment: The Unix systems have a setting named ["umask"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). It is a set of permissions and tells what permission bits to be reset when a new file is created. By default it is `0022` on most systems nowadays (it used to be `0002` twenty five years ago.) This means that any new file is created with at most `rwxr-xr-x`. The file mode can be changed later but probably PHP does not do it and uses the permissions only when it creates the file (and the _umask_ resets some of them).

Comment: @Justinas, no, it doesn't exist before `ini_set` is run.

@axiac, you're exactly right, I found the C source and it just uses the `open` command. Thanks! If you make that a top-level answer I'll mark it. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.h

Answer (score 0):

As [@axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664005/php-8-2-error-log-mode-wont-make-file-writeable?noredirect=1#comment133535403_75664005), by default Linux starts processes with a [umask of 0022](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php), which means it can't create any files with group or world write permissions.

The "solution" in PHP is to chmod the file after creation, but this is not recommended in multiprocess executions for reasons I don't really understand.

I think the solution is just to replace `error_log()` with a custom function that logs the error, then chmods the file.